# iOS - IGListKit - implement self sizing cell with UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, iglistkit

I am trying to implement IGListKit based CollectionView. It has 1 UILabel and 1 UIImageView.

Checked official examples too but couldn't manage to make it self sizing.

This is Cell class. In this class tried to add the code which is given in the official repository. The function I've used is preferredLayoutAttributesFitting:

```
import UIKit
import Stevia

class MainControllerCell: UICollectionViewCell {

lazy var userNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.numberOfLines = 1
    lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return lbl
}()

lazy var photoImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return iv
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.backgroundColor = .white

    contentView.sv(
        userNameLabel,
        photoImageView
    )   
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    contentView.layout(
        8,
        |-8-userNameLabel.height(20)-8-|,
        8,
        |-0-photoImageView-0-|,
        8
    )
}

override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    var newFrame = layoutAttributes.frame
    // note: don't change the width
    newFrame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
    layoutAttributes.frame = newFrame
    return layoutAttributes
}
}
```

This is SectionController:

```
import IGListKit

class MainSectionController: ListSectionController {

private var post: Post!

override init() {
    super.init()
    inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    minimumLineSpacing = 10
    minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
}

override func numberOfItems() -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionContext!.containerSize.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 75) // width / post.photo.getImageRatio() + 44
}

override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let userName = post.userName
    let photo = post.photo
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell

    guard let mainCollectionViewCell = collectionContext?.dequeueReusableCell(of: MainControllerCell.self,
                                                                              for: self,
                                                                              at: index) as? MainControllerCell else { fatalError() }

    mainCollectionViewCell.userName = userName
    mainCollectionViewCell.photoImageView.image = photo
    cell = mainCollectionViewCell

    return cell
}

override func didUpdate(to object: Any) {
    self.post = object as? Post
}
}
```

And lastly Controller:

```
import UIKit
import IGListKit

class MainController: UIViewController, ListAdapterDataSource {

lazy var adapter: ListAdapter = {
    let updater = ListAdapterUpdater()
    return ListAdapter(updater: updater, viewController: self)
}()

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    return collectionView
}()

var posts: [Post] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    posts = [Post(timeStamp: 0, userName: "onur", photoUrl: "xxx", photo: UIImage(named: "cat")!),
             Post(timeStamp: 1, userName: "onur", photoUrl: "xxx", photo: UIImage(named: "iPhoneMP")!),
             Post(timeStamp: 2, userName: "onur", photoUrl: "xxx", photo: UIImage(named: "placeholder")!),
             Post(timeStamp: 3, userName: "onur", photoUrl: "xxx", photo: UIImage(named: "random")!)]

    adapter.collectionView = collectionView
    adapter.dataSource = self

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.frame = view.bounds

    adapter.performUpdates(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: ListAdapterDataSource

func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
    return posts
}

func listAdapter(_ listAdapter: ListAdapter, sectionControllerFor object: Any) -> ListSectionController {
    return MainSectionController()
}

func emptyView(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}

}
```

What I am trying to implemet is making a Instagram like layout but less complicated. I won't add new views or anything.

In the preferredLayoutAttributesFitting method, I am getting the original image size. Not the scaled image's size.

The official examples are made with just labels. Before trying to implement this project I tried with just labels and constant sized UIImageView for profile photo. It is working good with it.

Not sure if the problem is with SteviaLayout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If im not wrong, IGLkit not support self sizing

Comment: [link](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Examples/Examples-iOS/IGListKitExamples/ViewControllers/SelfSizingCellsViewController.swift) this is the example they provided. @SPatel